# Mercurial Pre-Commit Hook: How to hook to python program in current directory?

Tags: python, windows, mercurial, pre-commit-hook

I'm trying to create a Mercurial hook that runs when the commits are being pushed to the main repository. I created a python script as given below:

```
# commit.py

from mercurial import ui, hg
from mercurial.i18n import gettext as _

def getV1ID(ui, repo, **kwargs):
    ui.write("The hook works!!!")
    v1id = ui.prompt('Enter the VersionOne ID')
    ui.write('VersionOne ID: '+v1id)
```

For each branch, this `commit.py` is duplicated as it contains mechanisms that needs to run before code gets pushed onto the main respository. The push should only be successful if those pre-push mechanisms pass. Users can modify their local commit.py so that they only run a subset of those pre-push operations depending on the project their working on and each person could be working on more than one project at a time. And so, `commit.py` cannot be a global python script that can reside in `.hg` folder.

To make mercurial run the local `commit.py`, in my mercurial.ini file (in C:\Users\UserName\mercurial.ini), I added the following statement:

```
[hooks]
prechangegroup = python:./commit.py:getV1ID
```

The python script runs if I place it inside `.hg` folder, but not when I do this. Can anyone help me shed light on this issue? Many thanks.

Comment: Does it work if you use an absolute path?

Comment: Giving absolute path defeats the whole purpose. Developers clone projects to different directories and they will be working on more than one project at a time. Having to constantly modify `mercurial.ini` doesn't seem to be the best solution. I did find a solution, which I shall post shortly.

Comment: I was trying to determine whether the problem was the particular relative path you were using or something else.

Comment: Yes. Relative paths don't work because the working directory, when invoking the hook script should either be an absolute path or it should be a python module in PYTHONPATH.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got this solution over IRC for Mercurial. As stated in one of my comments, the script for the hook should be specified as an absolute path or it should a python module in PYTHONPATH. Hence, I was suggested by `pmezard` over IRC that I should have a fixed script that invokes the local `commit.py`. This can be done as shown below:

In `mercurial.ini`, hook to a 'global' python-script that resides in `.hg` directory of the user's home as shown below:

```
[hooks]
preoutgoing = python:%USERPROFILE%\.hg\commit.py:run
```

The 'global' python-script, `commit.py` looks something like this:

```
from mercurial import ui, hg
import os

class Chdir:
    def __init__(self, newPath):
        self.savedPath = os.getcwd()
        os.chdir(newPath)

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        os.chdir(self.savedPath)

def run(ui, repo, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['source'] == 'push':
        with Chdir(repo.root) as dirchanged:
            import localcommit
            sys.exit(localcommit.main(ui, repo, **kwargs))
```

The `localcommit.py` in the repository's directory then gets run by the `global` commit-script and thus every repository can maintain its own customized commit-script.